# Combining several rows into one with no relation key

Tags: mysql, database, crystal-reports

Hey guys I'm kind of stuck here. I have a table that I need to combine several rows together.

The reason I need to combine several rows is because of the format my Crystal Reports will show this information. Thanks in advance.

My DB:

```
ID     Review              Date
------------------------------
2      2nd Review        9/1/2011
3      1st Review        3/6/2012
5      1st Review        2/12/2010
6      1st Review        6/12/2012
7      3rd Review        6/21/2011
```

My query should only output dates from 8/1/2011 or greater. My outcome should come out like this:

```
Review1            Date       Review2            Date        Review3            Date
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1st Review         6/12/2012   1st Review        3/6/2012     2nd Review       9/1/2011
```

Comment: So you want all reviews >= 8/1/2011 in one record in descending date order? Sounds like a job for dynamic SQL, though I have no idea how to do that in MySQL.

Comment: Yes thats what i would like to do. I know I could combine them in vb.net but it would be less efficient than doing it during a query. This is because I need to run this query for 180 different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL person myself, but you could use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to concatenate all the reviews and dates. It would probably mean you will have to perform some parsing on the Crystal side to make it look nicer/cleaner, but it should get everything onto one row for you.

Comment: Oh that's something i can work with. I will then split the string in vb.net and put its placement where needed thanks.